# Proof of Huppert's Theorem: where can I find it?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

I am looking for a proof of the Huppert's Theorem (1954):
"Every maximal subgroup of a finite group has prime index. So $G$ is supersoluble".
The proof on Robinsone is hard for me, and i found another one on this link(page 30):
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.28.2482&rep=rep1&type=pdf

But I don't understand the last part very well. Where can I find one which is not too difficult? Thanks

Comment: As an observation, your statement does not look the same as in the article you linked. The theorem there states: "If $G$ is a group such that all maximal subgroups have prime index, then $G$ is supersoluble". On the other hand, what you've written reads as: "Every finite group $G$ is supersoluble because all maximal subgroups of a finite group must have prime index". This is false: for instance, [$A_5$ has maximal subgroups of order $6$, $10$ and $12$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Alternating_group:A5) (thus indexes $10$, $6$ and $2$). In fact, $A_5$ is not supersoluble!

Comment: sorry, I intended "If the maximal subgroups of G all have prime
index then G is supersoluble", not what i wrote. Thanks for the observation anyway